# Using pymssql 2.2 not connecting to SQL server

Tags: freetds, pymssql

I was using a Macos system install of Python rather than a virtualenv. On this I had installed freetds and pymssql 2.1. This connected fine to a database using:

```
pymssql.connect(server='the.host.name\instance', user='username' etc . . ).
```

Realising that virtualenv is the proper way to do stuff I created a python 2.7-based virtual env and tried to pip install pymssql but got an error message. Quick hunt found the fix - namely to install from git with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git
```

but now my connection call returns a host-not responding error. I have used tsql to debug (TDSDUMP=stdout) and it looks like  the address\instance is causing a problem. Connecting to databases that have an address but no instance works fine

When I revert to my system-wide install and run it, I see that freetds resolves a port number for the database instance to a specific port (portNo).

Under my virtualenv, if I do my call to pymssql using this port number, my connection is fine.

```
pymssql.connect(server='the.host.name\instance', user='username', port='portNo', etc . . .)
```

whilst this work around works - I'm guessing that any change on the server might break it.

Any ideas why my pymssql call fails under these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Explicit is better than implicit. It is best to always include the port number (at least I do).

Answer (score 0):

Review the following two items:

- Make sure both installatons of pymssql (the global one and the one you get inside the virtualenv) are actually linked against the same FeeeTDS version. It could be you have more than one FreeTDS version installed and this is the reason you're seeing different behavior.
- When the *server* parameter contains `\` characters, make sure you either double quote it (`'the.host.name\\instance'`) or use raw string notation (`r'the.host.name\instance'`). This is standard Python development practice.